# Time and date entry condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have a Pinescript strategy which backtests trades made between two dates. It also has the option to stop trades being entered on the weekend.

Now I want an extra entry condition, where the strategy only opens trades if it occurs during these hours (GMT):

Sunday 1600 - 2359
Monday 0000 - 2359
Tuesday 0000 - 2359
Wednesday 0000 - 2359
Thursday 0000 - 2359
Friday 0000 - 1600
Saturday NO TRADES

Any idea how to do this? I can't figure out how to treat each day as it's own individual session.

I tried to create individual trading sessions for each day using the 'session' function and 'if' / 'or' functions to link them when creating the entry condition but didn't work. Pine didn't seem to let me use multiple sessions.